# Database column type change causes formatting issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a date and time column in my database.  Unfortunately, a 3rd party software which needs to read the database expects the date and time field to be of type `varchar(50)`...

When I change that field in the database to `varchar(50)`, all the dates go into a strange format.

When the column is of type `DateTime`, the date looks like this `2006-08-02 15:13:19.000`.

When I change that column to `varchar(50)`, the date ends up looking like this `Aug 2 2006 3:13PM`.

How do I change the date column to `varchar(50)`, but keep the date format to [ISO8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm)?

Comment: let that 3rd party software access your database with a view and convert the column within that view. ( see answer from Stanislovas Kalašnikovas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), getdate(), 121)
```